# OrderByKey works fine but OrderByChild gives unexpected results in firebase realtime database

Tags: android, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to order and filter the data using firebase realtime database. In one case I want to use OrderByKey (because I want new questions first and keys are generated using push feature) to sort the data, in another case I am using OrderByChild (because I want to sort using timestamp and in this case I don't use push but I use uid of the user as key).

In both case I want the newest thing/person(question/user) first so I want to order in descending order(at client side I even reverse that). So this is how I query after first query. First query just doesn't has `endAt(endAtKey)` part in below shown query.

**For OrderByKey:**

```
 ref.child("questions").orderByKey().endAt(endAtKey).limitToLast(10);


   //data at questions node looks like this
    {
  "-L1CbnCkXJiRT9MKpoP1" : {
    "mCorrectAnswer" : 1,
    "mOptionA" : "ueud",
    "mOptionB" : "h",
    "mOptionC" : "h",
    "mOptionD" : "h",
    "mProblem" : "4shsudududududududurududu"
  },
  "-L1Dd9x6ws5di2rf8yay" : {
    "mCorrectAnswer" : 1,
    "mOptionA" : "sh",
    "mOptionB" : "shsh",
    "mOptionC" : "hehs",
    "mOptionD" : "hssh",
    "mProblem" : "12ffsnsjsjdbxbddhdbdbddjebddb"
  }
```

**For OrderByChild:**

```
 mDatabaseReference.child("user_list").orderByChild("mTimeStamp")
                        .endAt(endAtKey).limitToLast(10);



     //data at user_list reference looks like this
     { 
    "VH78axip1bXN9dktsF4Az0oBche2": 
     "mTimeStamp": "1508782492973", 
     "mUserName": "Satyam Kumar" 
     }, 
    "2MedW9KSYTcB8I1qp0xcoNuwPEf1": 
     "mTimeStamp": "1508823085614", 
     "mUserName": "Thirunagari Yeshwanth" 
     }
```

I want to populate the RecyclerView with the data in groups of 10 so in `onDataChange` I save the key of first child received in `onDataChange` method.

```
     if (countCopy == 1) {  // while iterating through children this variable tells 
//the index of the loop. 

                                endAtKey = currentKey;
                                Log.e("endKey", endAtKey);
                            }
```

Now the problem I am facing is in subsequent fetches of data using the query above I am receiving the `endAtKey` fine(data received is also what is expected) for `OrderByKey` query but `endAtKey` is always the same for `OrderByChild` query and the data being received is always the same. 
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: When looking at the log from your `OrderByChild` query, is the `endAtKey` a uid or a timestamp?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes it is timestamp. Oh I think I got the problem with your comment, thank you I will try doing it with Uid. :)

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes I checked again I said wrong in previous comment. It is Uid that I am using. So I think I should do it with timeStamp because that is what we are querying with. I will check again with timestamp.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes Thank you so much. I used timestamp and everything went fine. Please write an answer for this I will accept. I am very grateful to you. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your `OrderByChild` query is that the `endAtKey` that you're getting is a key, instead of a `timestamp`. Remember that the OrderByChild is being used to query on the timestamp attribute, so your `endAtKey` must be a timestamp and not a key.